# why I meet a warning message when I try to compute covariance of two data frames by replacing NA

Tags: r, tidyverse

I try to replace NA of two data frame and compute the covariance between them. when I use this code, it works.

```
Weight <- Hawks%>%select(Weight)
Wing <- Hawks%>%select(Wing)

# since Weight and Wing has NA, so first replace NA
replacing_na <- function(vec){
  vec_no_na <- vec[!is.na(vec)]
  meanVal <- mean(vec_no_na)
  #meanVal <- mean(vec, na.rm=TRUE)
  
  vec[is.na(vec)] = meanVal
  return(vec)
}


new_Weight <- replacing_na(Weight)
new_Wing <- replacing_na(Wing)

cov(new_Wing, new_Weight)
```

however, when I use `{r} meanVal <- mean(vec, na.rm=TRUE)` it shows a warning "Warning: Parameter is neither a numeric nor a logical value: reply NA"

By contrast, when I turn **Weight** and **Wing** into vector, `{r} meanVal <- mean(vec, na.rm=TRUE)` it works

```
Weight <- Hawks$Weight
Wing <- Hawks$Wing

# since Weight and Wing has NA, so first replace NA
replacing_na <- function(vec){
  meanVal <- mean(vec, na.rm=TRUE)
  
  vec[is.na(vec)] = meanVal
  return(vec)
}


new_Weight <- replacing_na(Weight)
new_Wing <- replacing_na(Wing)

cov(new_Wing, new_Weight)
```

can anyone tell me why is this happen? Thank you very much

I try to replace NA with mean in data frame and compute covariance, however I meet problem when I use **mean** to directly replace NA, I want to figure out the reason but have no idea

Comment: That's because your `Weight` and `Wing` are single-column dataframes, not vectors. If you want vectors, you can use `pull` rather than `select` in your first two lines. Or use the `$` notation as in your second example.